# How to POST a query result to the Watson tone analyser hosted on the cloud at a specific address?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, get, endpoint

I have an SQL table up which has Artist, Song and Lyrics columns.

```
|id | artist | song | text|
 -------------------------
|1  | ABBA   | Blah | blah|
 -------------------------
|...| ...    | ...  | ... |
```

I also have a cloud hosted Watson tone app ready. I want to POST the lyrics of every row to the cloud hosted Watson tone analyser at this address: http://watson-row-analyser.eu-gb.cf.appdomain.cloud/#

I then want to use the resulting JSON to add the emotional scores of each song into a new table:

```
|id | artist | song | score  |
 ----------------------------
|1  | ABBA   | Blah | joy .93|
 ----------------------------
|...| ...    | ...  | ...    |
```

How do I do this? If anyone can help with the initial part of actually connecting the code I have written to the IBM cloud address so I can trial some POSTs that would be a great help!

I have already tried the code here:

```js
const https = require('https')

const data = JSON.stringify({
  todo: 'Buy the milk'
})

const options = {
  hostname: 'flaviocopes.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/todos',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': data.length
  }
}

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d)
  })
})

req.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error(error)
})

req.write(data)
req.end()
```

But in my instance, I am unsure as to what the hostname would be nor what the port is(as it is not hosted locally, rather on IBM 's cloud). So I have been unable to make the connection required. Is this on the right track? 
Below is my code so far - I can successfully query the table row by row just getting the lyrics from each.

```
    var mysql = require('mysql');

    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'root',
      password: '<password>',
      database: 'songdata'
      //insecureAuth : true
    });

    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      for (var i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        con.query(`SELECT text FROM songdata2ID WHERE id = ${i} 
       `, function(err, result, fields) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(result);

        });
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: a POST is not required here. It was a case of following the api endpoint rules for IBM's Watson Tone Analyser here https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/tone-analyzer

const ToneAnalyzerV3 = require('ibm-watson/tone-analyzer/v3');

```
const toneAnalyzer = new ToneAnalyzerV3({
  version: '{version}',
  iam_apikey: '{apikey}',
  url: 'https://gateway-wdc.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api'
});
```

Ensure that you set it up on IBM correctly first as an app. Then you will get  the url, api-key needed to make the connection to the endpoint.